# Android equivalent of iOS's UILocalNotification?

Tags: android, ios, uilocalnotification

I'm looking to use local notifications in my Android application and was wondering if Android had something like iOS's `UILocalNotification` available?

I like how `UILocalNotification` allows me to "schedule" one or more local notifications for a date in the future, and these fire regardless if the phone is awake or asleep (like a regular push notification).

Before I get into a mess with `AlarmManager` I would like to know if Android has a clean way of accomplishing this.

**EDIT: What is a `UILocalNotification`?**

*Instances of UILocalNotification represent notifications that an application can schedule for presentation to its users at specific dates and times. The operating system is responsible for delivering the notification at the proper time; the application does not have to be running for this to happen. Although local notifications are similar to remote notifications in that they are used for displaying alerts, playing sounds, and badging application icons, they are composed and delivered locally and do not require connection with remote servers.*

Comment: You might want to explain in a bit more detail what `UILocalNotification` is.

Answer (score 1):

- **Time-based trigger**

Considering your time-based trigger requirement, the `AlarmManager` appears to be the suitable solution (a dedicated training is available [here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)). You should use this with attention since alarms are cleared when device is shut down. So you should re-schedule your alarms when device reboot. You can solve this using a BroadcastReceiver declared in your manifest with the

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

intent filter.

- **Event-based behavior**

**EDIT (2014.04.19):** much more "Android equivalent of iOS's NSNotification?" oriented answer

For other uses of notifications under iOS, especially the [`NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` selector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName%3aobject%3auserInfo%3a)  (for event-based strategies for example, to notify a CoreData change for example), there are other available ways.

Maybe you could use the [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) concept available in the support library.

It is described as:

> Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process.

We can use this as:

```java
private void sendLocalNotification(){
    final Intent intent = new Intent("myLocalNotificationIdentifier");
    intent.putExtra("aKey", aValue);
    // ...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(aContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Then, you can register to a given notification in your `Activity` such as:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("myLocalNotificationIdentifier"));
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // specific job according to Intent and its extras...
    }

};
```

Otherwise, you can use the [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) library provided by [Square](http://square.github.io/) under the Apache License, Version 2.0.
It is described as

> Otto is an event bus designed to decouple different parts of your
>   application while still allowing them to communicate efficiently.

Nevertheless, depending on your requirements, you can use other Android concepts.
For example, if you want to be notified of a database change (in a project based on ContentProvider concept), you can use:

```java
aContentResolver.registerContentObserver(aContentObserver)
```

with method documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29).

Then the Observer will be invoked by a call such as:

```java
aContentResolver.notifyChange(anUri, null)
```

with method documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29).